# Kivy sometimes does not show widgets and images

Tags: python, kivy, widget

Does anyone know why kivy sometimes does not show new widgets on the screen. I have the identical code for several screens in an app writtin in .kv-language. It works fine in all screen but one screen wont show my the widgets and images.

I had the same problem a view times now, sometimes it works after a while but it is starting to get annoying since I can not continue coding before my widgets decide to show up.

Comment: This only affects the in .kv written widgets. The widgets written in python always show up.

Answer (score 0):

it often helps to just change the name of the screen and all its mentions. I still do not get what is going on, so if somebody has an answer please tell me.